# hash functions and horner's rule

Tags: computer-science

I want to use rule for evaluating the hash index of a string value.

> H(x) =x (a0+x (a1+x (a2+….)….)…))

Should the number of slots in the hash function and ‘x’ be co-prime/relative primes?

Please explain the reasoning behind it.
If it is not the case then what is the property these numbers must satisfy?

Comment: A general heuristic is that primes numbers are better for coefficients of hashing polynomial. A*X + B*Y = 0 (mod P) is rarely true when A & B are primes. If they have a common divisor D, it is more often 0 (mod P)

Comment: could you please suggest me an appropriate reading for this?